# Datareader Retrieving Data

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sqldatareader

I have Memberships and Bookings tables in a database containing an attribute cust_id, which is the primary key in Memberships and reference key in Bookings. When I am executing a data reader I want it to read cust_id values from membership table but it is reading it from the bookings table.

Also, when I compare two cust_id values, 1 taken from a textbox and the other taken a from database column, even though both are the same, but the comparison result is false. I have compared using string.equals(str1, str2) and have also compared the two directly using if statement. But in both cases, even if the string is the same, the result is otherwise.

My query is:

```
 str2 = "select Memberships.cust_id from Memberships, Bookings where   Memberships.cust_id = Bookings.cust_id"
Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand(str2, con)
con.Open()

Dim bookchk As SqlDataReader = cmd2.ExecuteReader  
While bookchk.Read()
Dim str1 As String = MskdTxtCustId.Text
Dim str3 As String = bookchk("cust_id")
MessageBox.Show(str1 & "," & str3 & String.Equals(str1, str3))

End While
    bookchk.Close()
    con.Close()
```

Comment: One major purpose for which i have joined the tables is that there are other validations which need attributes from the bookings tables like for example i have to check whether new booking overlaps with some already made booking or not

Comment: can you post your table definitions here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try explicitly stating that you want an `INNER JOIN` instead:

```
str2 = "select m.cust_id from Memberships AS M " &_
       " INNER JOIN Bookings AS B ON B.cust_id = M.cust_id;"
```

When comparing, use [`String.Compare()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkcaxw5y.aspx), and make sure you're trimming whitespace, just in case.

```
Dim str1 As String = MskdTxtCustId.Text.Trim()
Dim str3 As String = bookchk("cust_id").ToString().Trim()

Dim compareResult As Integer = String.Compare(s1, s2)
MessageBox.Show("compare str1: {0}, str3: {1}, result: {2}" , str1, str3, compareResult)

compareResult = String.Compare(s1, s2, True)
MessageBox.Show("Compare insensitive. result: {0}", compareResult)
```

Comment: Thnaks for your help, the problem of comparison is being solved but the problem in query still lies and it is still reading values from the Bookings table rather than the Memberships table

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by 'reading'. It's 100% taking the value from the m table, while joining on the b table, ensuring that each cust_id is in both. If you don't want that, then don't join.

Comment: I have 3 unique cust_id values in the Memberships table i.e. csc-01,csc-02,csc-03 and 6 Bookings in Bookings table all are for csc-01 and csc-02 and there is no booking for csc-03...When I'm selecting from Memberships i.e. m.cust_id then, as i have used message box to check the results, in MessageBox.Show(str1 & "," & str3 & String.Equals(str1, str3)) str3 never shows a value csc-03 but it is present in MEmberships table...i want bookchk to iterate through all the values in M.cust_id so that every time it is checked whether a customer has membership or not....I hope you have understood now

Comment: You need a LEFT OUTER JOIN instead of the INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

As for String compare: I always use Datareader.GetString(item) as in this Sub:

```
    If IsDBNull(Dr.Item(nr)) Then
        Return ""
    Else
        Return Dr.GetString(nr).TrimEnd
    End If
```

where nr identifies the row to fetch a value from. You are using some default method to convert the database value to the program variable. I rather write what I want.